# How do I undefine %{dist} using rpmbuild to build SRPM?

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm trying to work out my build process for RPMs.

When I produce source RPMs, it's including `%{dist}` in the file name. I would prefer that it only do that for the binary RPMs, since the source RPMs are not distribution specific.

The `dist` macro is defined in `/etc/rpm/macros.dist`. How would I undefine it while building source RPMs?

foo.spec:

```
Name:    foo
Version: 0.1
Release: 1%{?dist}
# etc...
```

Build command:

```
$ rpmbuild -bs foo.spec
$ ls ../SRPMS
$ foo-0.1-1.el6.src.rpm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple:

```
$ rpmbuild --undefine dist -bs foo.spec
```

Comment: That seems to [be new in RPM 4.10.2](http://www.spinics.net/lists/rpm/msg07689.html). A quick look at some CentOS mirrors shows that it wouldn't work in CentOS 6 (4.8) but should in CentOS 7 (4.11).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to conditionally check for what kind of package you are building, but you could try defining a macro at the command line only when building source packages. You would then conditionally checking for the macro at the top of your spec file:

```
$ rpmbuild -bs --define "mymacro 1" mypackage.spec
```

mypackage.spec:

```
%if 0%{?mymacro}
%undefine dist
%endif
```

To build a binary package, just omit the `--define "mymacro 1"`:

```
$ rpmbuild -bb mypackage.spec
```